# Gradle failed to produce android package

Tags: android, gradle, flutter

I want to release the .apk file in android studio using flutter.

When I run `flutter run` command, it runs and it builds the apk and install to the phone. But when I want to release the apk file using `flutter build apk --release` this command, it shows an error. And the error is `Gradle is failed to produce Android Package`

I used this code to the Gradle:

```
buildscript {
 repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com"
    }
}
dependencies {
    // Google Auth
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
    // Firebase Auth
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1'
}
}
```

After using this also it shows that error.

```
Initializing gradle...                                             12.4s
Resolving dependencies...                                          11.2s
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                                
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'... Done                      43.1s
Gradle build failed to produce an Android package.
```

It's ended with an error.

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Comment: Yes. I found the solution and I fixed that issue! Thank you!

Comment: I had the same issue after releasing an app bundle for split 32 and 64 in my build.gradle,

this solves it https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/27462#issuecomment-507229131

Comment: @Sabbir33 If you found the issue then consider adding as an answer. This will help people in the future facing the same/similar issue.

Comment: @Tokenyet If you're facing the same problem as I was, you might like to have a look at this answer of mine https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55990485/how-to-fix-gradle-build-failed-to-produce-an-android-bundle-package-in-flutte/58456581#58456581 It fixed my problem.

Answer (score 2):

**Short answer:** try to run 'flutter upgrade' in your terminal/upgrade dart sdk.
If doesn't work, try to downgrade your Gradle from 3.5.1 to 3.4.2

**Long answer:** I wanted to build the bundle, not the apk, but I had the same issue.
Searching online, I discovered that they fixed this problem on the master channel (I was on the stable once): https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/40445#issuecomment-531412497 .
If you are not familiar with channels, check out the (short) documentation: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Flutter-build-release-channels
I decided to switch to the master channel => I entered 'flutter build bundle' and... => more issues appeared!
So I typed 'flutter channel' and it started downloading the Dart SDK.
In the end, I switched back to the stable version and voilà!
I was able to produce my bundle!
So how did I solve the problem?
Well, I simply updated my tools in a strange and original way!

**[EDIT]:** I encountered the problem again, but this time I solved it downgrading Gradle from 3.5.1 to 3.4.2 (android > build.gradle).
For more information, check out this answer: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/40445#issuecomment-557614757

Answer (score 1):

- Edit Configurations

[image]

- Add Build flavor

[image]

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/44796#issuecomment-610860388

Answer (score -3):

try 
`flutter clean` first,

and try

`flutter build apk`

Comment: What you have said I have tried. But that did not work. The issue was different. I found that out and I fixed that. Thank you.