# How to fix "Gradle build failed to produce an Android bundle package." in Flutter

Tags: build, flutter, android-gradle-plugin, android-app-bundle

On running 
`flutter build appbundle` I am getting the following error:
Gradle build failed to produce an Android bundle package.

When running in verbose mode this is what I additionally get:

```
#0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:24:3)
#1      _buildGradleProjectV2 (package:flutter_tools/src/android/gradle.dart:585:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      buildGradleProject (package:flutter_tools/src/android/gradle.dart:331:14)
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      buildAppBundle (package:flutter_tools/src/android/app_bundle.dart:43:10)
<asynchronous suspension>
#4      BuildAppBundleCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/build_appbundle.dart:43:11)
<asynchronous suspension>
#5      FlutterCommand.verifyThenRunCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:545:18)
#6      _asyncThenWrapperHelper.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/runtime/libasync_patch.dart:77:64)
#7      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1132:38)
#8      _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1029:19)
#9      _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:126:18)
#10     Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:639:45)
#11     Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:668:32)
#12     Future._complete (dart:async/future_impl.dart:473:7)
#13     _SyncCompleter.complete (dart:async/future_impl.dart:51:12)
#14     _AsyncAwaitCompleter.complete.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/runtime/libasync_patch.dart:33:20)
#15     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1124:13)
#16     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1021:19)
#17     _CustomZone.bindCallback.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:947:23)
#18     _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:41:21)
#19     _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:50:5)
#20     _runPendingImmediateCallback (dart:isolate/runtime/libisolate_patch.dart:115:13)
#21     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate/runtime/libisolate_patch.dart:172:5)
```

I am on Flutter stable channel v1.2.1.

I can build an apk without a problem though.
I can also build an appbundle from another Flutter project.

Based on the error messages above how would you start to find the issue?
What might be the problem here?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I have similar issue with the same error messages. 
(Build Release APK successfully but failed to build app bundle) 
The solution that works for me is to upgrade the Android Gradle Version.
Below are the config that works for me (You may upgrade to the latest version also):

1. **/android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties**:

`distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.2-all.zip`

2. **/android/build.gradle**:

   ```
   buildscript {
       repositories {
          google()
          jcenter()
         }

       dependencies {
          classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I had to also remove references to kotlin in my gradle files (three different places)

Comment: Before further investigating the issue, i think there is one trick you can try is to create a new flutter project with the latest Android SDK, Android Gradle Plugin [link](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin) and Flutter Version to make sure your environment is able to build a app bundle first. Then you can copy the dart files in '/lib' to the new project to build app bundle from now on, or try to diff the gradle setting between the new project and your existing project to see whats the problem. (In case you are really having the exact same error message in this post)

Comment: If anyone else runs into this and this solution did not solve the problem, check if you are using the android.tools.build:gradle with version 3.5.0. There is currently an issue with that version, see [this flutter issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/38934). Temporarily downgrading to 3.4.2 solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 2):

I commented list of APIs in **app.gradle** and then it works:

```
android {
    splits {

        abi {

            //include "x86", "x86_64", "armeabi", "armeabi-v7a", "arm64-v8a"

        }
    }
  }
```

Comment: but don't you need that line so that the app works on 32bit and 64bit devices??

Comment: @F-1 True, This line doesn't make any problem if you trying to build bundle apk..., It happen if you trying to build a normal release apk. So you have to leave it when you need the advantage of it when using bundle !...

Comment: I figured it out, you can't build an app bundle in Flutter you have to do it in Android Studio for now.

Answer (score 2):

There is a multitude of reasons for which you might encounter a frustrating problem like `Gradle build failed to produce an Android bundle package`.

As of @Tam Tam Tam's answer, first try to update your gradle and android gradle plugin to a latest version.

If that does not fix your problem, then try to disable all the different architectures and set `universalApk` to `false` in your `android/app/build.grade` in splits section. Put something like this:

```
splits {
        abi {
            enable true
            reset()
            // include 'x86', 'armeabi-v7a', 'x86_64'
            universalApk false
        }
    }
```

This suggestion was provided here:
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/27462#issuecomment-507229131

It happens because gradle generates the apk following a convention, eg, `app-<architecture-name>.apk`, which is not understandable by flutter, it expects apk names in another format, eg, simply `app.apk`. Disabling all different architectures name bring them to a common understanding :)

If that is also not work, then try to remember if you change your package name `com.example.packagename` to something your own personal like `com.mywebsite.packagename`. If you have done it, then you probably changed it everywhere needed, for example, in `build.gradle`s and `AndroidManifest.xml` but you might forgot to change it in your java (or kotlin class).

To make your new package name works, you also have to change the package name in `src/main/java/com/mywebsite/packagename/MainActivity.java` (in case of kotlin, it's `src/main/kotlin/com/mywebsite/packagename/MainActivity.kt`)

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my senario:

I'm using a remote machine from CI to sign apk with release sign config.
So I removed `buildTypes.release.signConfig` in `build.gradle` like this:

```
    buildTypes {
        release {
            // signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            minifyEnabled true
            useProguard true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
```

This makes the name of the output apk change to `app-release-unsigned.apk` but flutter expects `app-release.apk`, which leads to `Gradle build failed to produce an Android bundle package.`

After adding `signingConfig signingConfigs.release` back the problem was solved.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I added flavor to my project and forgot to add flavor name to Run/Debug Configuration.

Comment: Wasted 2 hours debugging this, and if you hadn't written this I would have wasted two more.  So silly of me to forget, but so easy to get tunnel vision thinking the problem is something bigger than it really is.  Appreciate you noting this to jog my memory.

Answer (score 1):

I lost some part of the config of the default project.gradle

```
rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, migrating to AndroidX fixed everything:

https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/androidx-compatibility

Answer (score 0):

For me, I had *signingConfig signingConfigs.debug* line missing in my release config of app's `build.gradle` file. But error I was getting is the same "Gradle build failed to produce an Android bundle package".

```
android {
    ...
    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me changing my gradle version as following line solved the issue. (I was using a higher version)

**android/build.gradle**

```
  dependencies {
     classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'
  }
```